# SQL Oracle: Create a new column with values of 'Approved', 'Denied', or 'Not specified' when substring is found in previous column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called ANES.ANESTH_COMMENTS that holds unstructured comments. If ANES.ANESTH_COMMENTS has some variation of "Approved", "Approve", "yes", "Either", or "verified", I want a column called STATUS to have a value of 'Approved'.
If ANES.ANESTH_COMMENTS has some variation of 'Denied', 'Not approved', 'no', or 'declined', then STATUS is  'Denied'.

I keep running into problems where the substring is missed because of case sensitive, commas, spaces, characters before and after the substring. For example, 'approved' is missed when I use '%Approved%' and 'Denied, ' is missed when I use '%Denied%'.

In my select clause, I have the following:

```
,CASE 
        WHEN ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, approve,%'
        or ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, yes,%'
        or ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, either,%'
        or ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, verified,%'
            THEN 'Approved' 
        when ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, denied,%'
         or ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, not approved,%'
         or ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, no,%'
         or ', ' + anes.anesth_comments +',' LIKE '%, declined,%'
            then 'Denied'
            else 'Not specified'
        END AS status
```

I'm running into errors.

I had this before but it was failing to catch the different variations:

```
case
        when anes.anesth_comments like '%Approved%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%approved%' 
        OR anes.anesth_comments like '%APPROVED%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: yes%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: Yes%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: YES%'
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%Approve%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%approve%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%Either%'
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%EIther%'
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%yes%'
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%verified%'
            then 'Approved'
        when ser.name = 'Bariatrics' or
        anes.anesth_comments like '%Denied%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%denied%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%DENIED%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%NOT APPROVED%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: No%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: no%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: NO%' 
        or anes.anesth_comments like '%: DENIED %'
        or anes.anesth_comments like '% Declined%'
            then 'Denied'
        else 'Not specified'
    end as status
```

My biggest issue is catching the substring when there's words or characters before or after it. Also, when there's punctuation or spaces before or after the substring.

I appreciate any help!

The comments are usually more than 200 characters and follow different syntax from each other

Comment: First solve for case by casting to `upper()` or `lower()`. Then remember that case expressions stop once a match is found, so "not approved" would be first caught by "approved" based on your current order.

Comment: Note that Oracle has `||` as concatenation operator. E.g. `', ' || anes.anesth_comments || ','`. The ANSI SQL way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `upper()` or `lower()` when wanting to use the `like` operator. Here's how your base case expression should appear:

```
case 
 when upper(anes.anesth_comments) like '%NOT APPROVE%' 
   or upper(anes.anesth_comments) like '%DENIED%'
   or upper(anes.anesth_comments) like '%DECLINE%'
 then 'Denied'
 when upper(anes.anesth_comments) like '%APPROVE%' 
   or upper(anes.anesth_comments) like '%VERIFIED%' 
   or upper(anes.anesth_comments) like '%EITHER%' 
   or upper(ser.name) like '%BARIATRICS%'
 then 'Approved'
 else 'Not Specified'
end as status
```

You'll likely run into problems if you simply add `%YES%` or `%NO%` to your expression, so you should look at examples and determine the best way to include Yes/No in your expression. You may need to add additional criteria such as:

```
or (upper(comments) like '% YES%' and upper(comments) not like '%YESTERDAY%')
```

You should try to find a better word(s) that could go along with Yes/No for your conditions.

Comment: thank you so much! I did find better words to go with yes/no

Comment: Should this resolve the question, then please consider marking the Accept answer flag.